# Codigniter Unable to find model when installed on subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I created my application in XAMPP and it worked fine, now when I have shifted it on my website's subdomain. When I try to open the login page of my application it gives error `Unable to locate the model you have specified`

**Directory Structure on subdomain:**

```
public_html/
           Subdomain/
                     Codeigniter/
                                 application/
                                           models/
                                           views/
                                           controllers/
```

Login Page of my Codeigniter application is:

**On local host**

```
http://localhost/INvoice/index.php/admin/Login_Controller/
```

**On website**

```
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php/admin/Login_Controller/
```

Comment: have you checked your .htaccess? can you post it?

Comment: @idioteque it has only one line `Deny from all`

Comment: thank you! Could you please provide me with your model file,class declaration and model call?(copy/paste)

Answer (score 0):

In xampp for codeigniter I use this htaccess with windows 7 & 8.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I use sub domains on live and that htaccess works fine so long it is in main directory of the subfolder and parent directory. I think because you have deny all which is causing you issue.

**Main Directory**

[image]

**Sub Dir Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Basically I have problems in my file naming convention for models. I have been using Capital letters in File Name i.e. `Login_Model.php` and when I changed it to `login_model.php` it is fixed. 
Just to you know, My `.htaccess` is still empty but I have no problem in my URLs.